# How to free previous intent when calling startActivity() with new intent

Tags: android, android-activity

I am facing this issue:

- Create intent from an `Activity`
- Then at Home screen, I call `startActivity` with this intent
- After I `startActivity` with intent A then intent B, the intent A still remain behind

I want:

- free intent A when I `startActivity` with intent B
- press BACK from any intents will back to Home screen

Please help me.

```
tvAbout = (TextView) mSettingsMenu.findViewById(R.id.tv_about);
tvAbout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AboutActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
});
tvProfile = (TextView) mSettingsMenu.findViewById(R.id.tv_profile);
tvProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
});
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your code

**A--->>> to B Activty (Here A finished when B Activity is opened)**

```
 Intent addIntent = new Intent(this, B_AboutActivity.class);
                  startActivity(addIntent);
                  finish();
```

Then press Back button open the **A Activty** finish the **B activity**

```
@Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A_Activty.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. Finish then override pressed Back key maybe good choice in this case. I just have a question, how should I do if I call fragments in B activity?

Comment: you want to call the Fragment from Activity B?

Answer (score 0):

The second time you start a Activity, the intent is received in a method called onNewIntent. You can set the intent for the activity at this time.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```